# Chrome Extension local storage not working

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, local-storage

I have written a simple html page that has one input and three links.

"OK" --> Stores whatever is in the filed to local storage

"WhoamI" --> Alerts with the value that was saved to local storage

"Check" --> if that value is "asd", it replys with "asd" or not "Asd"

Pretty simple and I have tested this as just a regular html page and it works. All of the functions behave as they should.

Here is index.html

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title> System Information </title>
<script src="main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" name="text" id="text">
<a href="#" onclick="saveChanges(); return false">OK</a>
<a href="#" onclick="who(); return false">WhoAmI</a>
<a href="#" onclick="check(); return false">check</a>

</body>
</html>
```

and here is the javascript main.js

```
function saveChanges() {
  var theValue = text.value;

localStorage["ChromeLogin"] = theValue;
}
function who() {
    alert(localStorage["ChromeLogin"]);
}
function check(){
    var test = localStorage["ChromeLogin"];
    if (test == "asd"){
        alert("it is asd");
    }else{
        alert("It is NOT asd");
    }
}
```

[image]

However, when I import the same exact code as a google chrome extension, everything stops working.

Here is my manifest.json code.

```
{
  "name": "testLocalStorage",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "Capture a tab",
  "options_page": "index.html",

  "manifest_version": 2,

  "browser_action": {
  "default_title": "Capture tab"
  },
  "permissions" : ["tabs", "<all_urls>", "storage"]
}
```

I am assuming this is the issue:
[image: Issue Screen shot]

I read throughout [this](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy.html) but I could not figure it out.

Any help will be appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you did not completely understand the [link](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy.html) you referred to :), there is an [inline script section](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy.html#relaxing-inline-script) in referenced link, which says [inline script will not be executed.](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy.html#JSExecution)

***Changes Made to index.html***

1) Removed all **INLINE JS** of

`<a href="#" onclick="saveChanges(); return false">OK</a>`

`<a href="#" onclick="who(); return false">WhoAmI</a>`

`<a href="#" onclick="check(); return false">check</a>`

to

`<a href="#" id="ok">OK</a>`

`<a href="#" id="who">WhoAmI</a>`

`<a href="#" id="check">check</a>`

by assigning id's

**Final index.html**

```
<html>
<head>
<title> System Information </title>
<script src="main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" name="text" id="text">
<a href="#" id="ok">OK</a>
<a href="#" id="who">WhoAmI</a>
<a href="#" id="check">check</a>

</body>
</html>
```

***Changes made to main.js***

1) Added Event handlers to all 3 functions on click of `<a/>` tags as shown here

> window.onload = function () {
>
> ```
> document.getElementById('ok').onclick = saveChanges;
> document.getElementById('check').onclick = check;
> document.getElementById('who').onclick = who;
> ```
>
> }

**Final main.js**

```
function saveChanges() {
  var theValue = text.value;

  localStorage["ChromeLogin"] = theValue;
}
function who() {
    alert(localStorage["ChromeLogin"]);
}
function check(){
    var test = localStorage["ChromeLogin"];
    if (test == "asd"){
        alert("it is asd");
    }else{
        alert("It is NOT asd");
    }
}
window.onload=function (){
    document.getElementById('ok').onclick=saveChanges;
    document.getElementById('check').onclick=check;
    document.getElementById('who').onclick=who;
}
```

***Changes Made to manifest.json***

1) Eliminated un-necessary permissions section in `manifest.json`

**Final manifest.json**

```
{
  "name": "testLocalStorage",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "Capture a tab",
  "options_page": "index.html",

  "manifest_version": 2,

  "browser_action": {
  "default_title": "Capture tab"
  }
}
```

**Final Output**

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. This was great. Now I see what they mean "No inline" :D